# How to Approach Coworker About Eating Habits?

Tags: colleagues

A co-worker of mine frequently has candy or chips while he's working. I don't mind if he's snacking, the problem is what he does while snacking...he chews with his mouth open. I don't sit close enough to see what he's chewing, but I can certainly hear it, it's somewhat gross and is a distraction.

Often times I resort to just putting on my headphones to block out the noise, but that shouldn't be necessary. I want to ask him about trying to close his mouth when chewing but am unsure about how to approach this.

Is this something I should even approach? Should it be left to management to bring it up to him?

Comment: Is the problem hearing loud chewing noises or seeing food being chewed with the mouth open (or both)? You seem to touch on both of those in your question.

Comment: Edited, I hear it but don't see it.

Comment: If you were able to see what he was chewing would it help process the sounds better and make it easier for you?

Comment: ick, no!!! Are you serious, or was that a wind-up?

Comment: @Ryguy How is he going to know that their is a(perceived) problem, if no one tells him?

Comment: I have the same issue. Coworker eats literally once every hour for about 15-20 minutes, always with his mouth open, always loudly in a very quiet office, and breathes in and out of his mouth while doing it. He brings a huge bin of peanut butter, eggs, sardines, all the smelly things. It's awful. Bringing headphones into work has helped immensely! I know you said shouldn't be necessary but it's either get headphones, talk to him, or talk to HR.

Answer (score 4):

Try this next time he does it and there isn't too many people around.

"Hey dude, you may not realize this but...  *whisper* you are chewing with your mouth open." Don't forget to try and smile so he's knows you don't hate him.

Comment: Or “Dude, I can see the stuff in your mouth when you’re eating, and it’s pretty gross!”  This should provide enough embarrassment to stop this behaviour.

Comment: While I agree with both of these, it might be better to focus on the noise, as that makes it about what he is eating, and so less likely to be perceived as a criticism of him.